# Check if items are in sequence regardless of other items in between

Tags: php, arrays, regex, string, strpos

Given a sequence ALJ

I want to check if this sequence exists in another sequence like

AASDALLLACCCCJ

regardless of other elements in between.

My idea is to first strip non matching characters with php.

```
$string_looking_for = "ALJ";
$string_haystack = "AASDALLLACCCCJ";
preg_match("/[".$string_looking_for."]/g",$string_haystack,$matches);
```

And then just do a simple strpos in the resulting matches.

Would there be a better way?

Comment: the order of crucial characters doesn't matter, right? I mean, would this `LAALJJA` be valid?

Comment: What if your string has for example a J before the first L? Does it matter?

Comment: *And then just do a simple strpos in the resulting matches* - what for?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest I would like the order of crucial characters to matter
The strpos would be on the string that contains only the crucial characters.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte then the string would not match the haystack, as the order is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this :

```
$string_looking_for = "/A.*L.*J/";
$string_haystack = "AASDALLLACCCCJ";
preg_match($string_looking_for,$string_haystack,$matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Using `.*` to ignore characters in between, if any.

Comment: Nice, it does not match "AASDAJLLLACCCC"; for example, which is great!